# Print RDLC report from server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, rdlc

I'm creating a RDLC report and printing it from ASP.Net. When i try this in local machine it works fine. But when deploying in the server the printer settings are not valid.

//Code

```
 if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");

        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

       // printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "HP LaserJet 3055 PCL5";

        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
```

From the above code it throws me an exception "cannot find default printer". Tried to add the printer name which exists in the client machine but still didn't work.

**I need to print the report in the client machine.**

Don't know where to change. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you are doing something you arent' supposed to do.

If you have a ASP.NET Website, that has a RDLC report in the site. If I, access that report, I would like to print in my machine, not in the server. Are you sure, that you want to make the server to print the report? Shouldn't the client/browser to issue the print command?

If your server is in a datacenter, and I'm at my home, where should the printing be done? Unless you want to print in the server (Mail Merge stickers, for example).

Comment: Updated the question. Need to print in the client machine from code behind. How can i do?

Comment: Look and the comment I added to the Serv answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to access the client's printer settings. What you are doing is access the servers printer, which, if I am right, is not installed.

You can print accesing browser/ javascript functionality by calling `window.print()` in javascript,because the browser is running client-side and has access to the printers. But accessing the clients system resources directly would be a huge security flaw.

Maybe there is an obscure workaround/hack, but it would be a bad solution

Comment: Now i need to print it in the client machine. How can i do? from the code behind.

Comment: Look here how you can print in the client: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/569335/Automatically-Printing-an-RDLC-file-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Yeah, in the end it comes down to javascript.